# Saving animated SVG from a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, flash

There's an Internet Site with a Chinese dictionary that uses animations to show you the proper way to write Chinese characters. I'm not entirely sure how the animations work, but they appear to SVG-based. You can find an example of the animation here:

http://ce.linedict.com/dict.html#/cnen/entry/e1d0a1716f89470d88087dce285914a1

Be sure to click **"Strokes"** to view the animation.

So here"s the challenge I'm facing: I was wondering if there is any way to download the animations so that they can be viewed offline. The reason I want to do this is to add them to Anki, a flashcard app that I use on my iPad when I'm on the go (i.e. offline).

I tried examining the element in Firefox and saving the inner HTML of the element as a separate file, but that results in an static page. Doing the same in Safari is impossible as the inner HTML keeps changing as the animation is rendered, which makes me think that the inner HTML is being rendered on the fly by a separate (?) Java / (?) Jquery script nested somewhere on the site. Unfortunately, my knowledge of Java is rudimentary at best, and although I've started a tutorial online to get myself acquainted with the code, I think it'd be ages before I can figure out what's going on here. That's why I'm looking for help from you guys who have more experience with webpages than I do.

So is there any way to save the animation for offline use, either as a code or a svg / animated gif file? Anki, the flashcard app I'm using, uses HTML to render its content in a similar manner to web browsers (and as far as I know there are ways to integrate JavaScript).

I guess that I could use screen capturing programs to record the animation and save it as a .gif file, but given the fact that there are about 3500-5000 Chinese characters that a learner must master to be fluent in Chinese, that would take a hell of a time, so I'm looking for something that can be Scriptable (I have some working understanding of Apple Scripting, and could take it from myself there once I understand how to the animation works).

I'd appreciate any help or suggestion that could bring me any further.

---Edit on 2015-05-23:

Like I mentioned in a reply to Robert below, I've had a look at the DOM structure of a different entry, this time for a single character rather than a multi-character word. When the stroke order animation button on the page is activated, the following code can be found in the DOM structure:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_strokeFileName" value="1200爸.swf">
```

as you can see there seems to be a reference to a file name with a flash-based animation. If the animation is indeed contained in an .swf file, it should be possible to download it for offline use, right? However, I'm baffled as to how the browser stitches up the URL under which the animation can be found so that I could download it. Can anyone help?

Here's the link to the page: http://ce.linedict.com/dict.html#/cnen/entry/cca145dd67574395a5a28af08a3afb30

Comment: That is svg animation. Check https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/

Comment: Not really, its basically javascript creating and modifying SVG elements.

Comment: Thanks guys for the info. @Ketan: I've had a look at the css link, and while it's seems really helpful for someone trying to create animations themselves, I don't see how it should help me here (though it may be just because the article is too technical for me and I'm not seeing the wood for the trees).  @ Robert: I've had another look at the DOM structure of a different entry with a single character rather than a multi-character word. I'm not sure if its SVG or .swf animation anymore. See my edit above for more detail.

Comment: Look at the page using a DOM inspector and you'll see SVG elements being created and deleted to do the character animation. That part isn't flash.

Comment: @RobertLongson. Thanks, I've just followed your advice. You're absolutely right, SVG are being created and deleted on the fly. However, I also discovered something more. Spent an hour or so looking at the JavaScript and it seems that we're both right. The source of the animation is stored in an .swf file, which is then converted to HTML5 using Google's Swiffy algorithm (see: https://developers.google.com/swiffy/convert/upload). My knowledge of JavaScript is very rudimentary, so I can't follow how the script knows where the original .swf file is stored. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple tool (script snippet, 16 lines of code): https://gist.github.com/VityaSchel/bc2a83e330661c2bae580ebb4aab05cf

It records svg changes using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface. I used it to record animations of "d" argument but you can modify this script to record all changes in svg structure and attributes.

One major issue with this tool is that it records unevenly, so some parts may be slightly slower than others.

```js
let recordedChanges = []
let startRecordingSVG = () => { recordedChanges = [] }
let stopRecordingSVG = () => { console.log(JSON.stringify(recordedChanges)) }

let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
    for(const record of mutationRecords) {
        if(record.attributeName === 'd') {
            recordedChanges.push(record.target.getAttribute('d'))
        }
    }
})

observer.observe($0, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true
})

/* USAGE */
// 1. Select target svg (or better it's parent, because svg may be overwritten) in Elements panel
// 2. Paste this into Console
// 3. Paste startRecordingSVG() into console
// 4. Do something so animation plays
// 5. Paste stopRecordingSVG() into console
// 6. An array with all animation keyframes will be printed in JSON format, use it to transform to lottie animation or CSS keyframes
```

In addition to that I created a function to convert this array to CSS keyframes:

```js
function arrayFramesToCSSKeyframes(array) {
    let frames = '', i = 1
    for(let framePath of array) {
        const percentage = i/array.length*100
        const frameCode = []
        frames += `  ${Math.round(percentage)}% {\n`
        frames += `    d: path("${framePath}");\n`
        frames += `  }\n\n`
        i++
    }
    return `@keyframes frames {\n${frames}\n}`
}
```